# How do I "recycle" a static class in selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, salesforce

I have been trying to write a Selenium project to test against a Salesforce app. After much trial and numerous error messages popping up intermittently in various places, I think I narrowed it down to something on Saleforces' end. It appears to get hung up after the 10th record. When I tested the next 10 it got hung up at the same spot. I am thinking this may be some sort of DoS defense used by Salesforce. I was also thinking that after every 9 records I would "recycle" the web driver. Is this possible, as it is a static object (following the code by a guru on Pluralsite).

```
 static OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeOptions options = new OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeOptions();
 public static IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\mydocs\", options);
```

But if I close the browser using

```
 driver.Close();
```

or

```
driver.Quite();
```

the entire static class gets hosed. I do not use static classes much. Is there a way to "clear" the class?

Comment: Are you automating somebody else's website without their permission? Of course you will get shut down! What you are proposing will not work: such a "defense" is normally done by originating IP. If you keep it up, you can get your provider black-listed.

Comment: You clearly have a misunderstanding about what a `static` member is. You cannot `recycle` a `static` class by it's very nature but looking at your problem it's got nothing to do with being a `static` class or not. What exactly is the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just write a method that resets it to a new instance?

```
public static void resetDriver() {
    driver.quit();
    driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\mydocs\", options);
}
```